# How to change the colour of a field in view odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change a field colour based on its value.its a selection field.
field name--status
success--green
failed--red
manual--black
I tried following codes but failed to get desired output:
1.

```
<field name="status" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('status','!=','manual')]}"/>
<field name="status" style="color:green;" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('status','!=','success')]}"/>
<field name="status" style="color:red;" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('status','!=','failed')]}"/>
```

When I executed tthis code,view shows string name but no value

2.

```
 <field name="status" readonly="1" options='{"fg_color": "red:status == "failed"; green:status == "success"; black:status == "manual"}'/>
```

I got an error while running this code :expected } got(name)

3.

```
 <field name="status" readonly="1" colors=="red:status == 'failed'; green:status == 'success'; black:status == 'manual'"/>
```

No colours appeared when I executed this code

Answer (score 1):

```
<field name="date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('start','progress','close'))]}"/>
<field name="date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('draft','progress','close'))]}" style="background-color:palegreen;" />
<field name="date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('draft','start','close'))]}" style="background-color:red;" />
<field name="date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('draft','progress','start'))]}" style="background-color:yellow;" />
```

You change field name and status according your requirements. It's work fine for me.